# How to display the result from SQLite db to html?

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I am currently learning to build a small web-app. I want to show the list of employees in the web page, and later the ability to add a new employee data to the database. I am using SQlite db and Python Flask. 
But I am stuck at this error message: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rows' referenced before assignment`. So my question is, how do I fetch the content of my SQlite db and show them on my webpage? I'd like to show it as a table as well.

Here's my HTML code:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}


{% block body %}
    <h1> Employees </h1>
    <ul>
        {% for employee in employees %}
        <li> {{ employee }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <a href = "/add">Add a new employee</a>
{% endblock %}
```

And my `python` code:

```
@app.route("/")
def tasks():
    rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM employees")
    return render_template("employee_list.html", rows= rows)
```

Anybody can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use macro

```
{% macro render_comment(emp) %}
   <li>{{ emp }}</li>
{% endmacro %}
<ul>
     {% for emp in employees %}
          {{ render_comment(emp) }}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and change

`return render_template("employee_list.html", rows= rows)`

to

`return render_template("employee_list.html", employees= rows)`

Comment: Thanks for your help! It somewhat works, but the webpage shows the code too: `{'ID': 1, 'name': 'Dan Milano', 'position': 'HR Manager', 'classification': 'Level 2', 'create_date': '2020-01-28'}` do you know why?

Comment: I know my question is about a list, but can you advise how do I display it as a table? Thanks!

Comment: this is result of your query , to show in table you need to use form ( i am considering you are using some basic html only) [go through this](https://dzone.com/articles/flask-101-adding-editing-and-displaying-data) this will help you to show the result in table form